# Export Formats for CSV File in Stimulsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, report, stimulsoft

Hi, I'm trying to export a report to CSV format via code, using Stimulsoft Reports .Net v2.3.0, but i'cant find de property to set "Bands Filter: Data and Headers/Footers". This property exists at the Report Viewer, but i need know how to set it in code. 
I attach the the cap of the properties at Report Viewer
Thanks :(

[image: The cap of the properties at Report Viewer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did this:

```
config.DataExportMode = StiDataExportMode.Data;
config.DataExportMode = StiDataExportMode.DataAndHeadersFooters;
config.DataExportMode = StiDataExportMode.AllBands;
```

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

The name of the export option incode is

```
StiCsvExportSettings.DataExportMode
```

Comment: And how to use this option dude?